# Azure Cloud Service SSL redirect from Staging to Production slot

Tags: redirect, azure, ssl

I have set up SSL on the production slot of my cloud service. In my Web.Release.config I have a rule to redirect from http to https. I deploy to staging with the Release configuration so that when I swap with production the redirect will take place.  However, this causes my staging to redirect to the production environment, which means that I can never really test my staging deployment (basically I can test that the redirect is taking place).

I feel that this setup is wrong. Does anyone have any insight into whether my set up is incorrect?

**EDIT**: Web.Release.config rule:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <rules>
        <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.myDomain\.com$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.myDomaim.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

**EDIT 2** I ended up going with @BenV 's approach of making sure that the redirect rule does not match my staging slot's URL.  Makes sense :D

Comment: What does your rule look like?

Comment: @kwill Added config rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually with your `CanonicalHostNameRule1` rule.  It basically says "redirect anything that is not www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com.

Since your staging slot is something like www.mydomain-staging.com, it gets redirected.

There's a few ways to go about fixing this, depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish with that rule.  One would be to add a rule to not redirect for staging.

```
<conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.myDomain\.com$" negate="true" />
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.myDomain-staging\.com$" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

This will do the redirect for anything that is not www.mydomain.com AND not www.mydomain-staging.com.

Another way to write this without referencing the staging slot would be:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myDomain\.com$" />
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*myDomain\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
</conditions>
```

This checks if the request is for myDomain.com (without the "www") OR myDomain.azurewebsites.net (with or without the "www") and does the redirect if either of those is true.  Since the staging URL would not match either of those it would be ignored.

(Disclaimer: I didn't test the regex's, but you get the idea)

Comment: Currently, to save costs, I delete my staging slot after a successful deployment and swap.  This means that my staging URL changes with each deployment. Because of this, I would not be able to have a consistent rule to prevent redirects when hitting the staging URL. In regards to the Canonical Hostname Rule, frankly, I am not sure why it's there :) I looked online and I think most people use it for SEO purposes. I could be wrong though.  @benv

Comment: Typically it's either to redirect myDomain.com to www.myDomain.com (or vise versa) or else to redirect myDomain.azurewebsites.net to www.myDomain.com.

Comment: Also, you can specify the name of the deployment slot, so wouldn't you give it the same name every time you create it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean "specifying the name of the deployment slot"?  I have been deploying using Visual Studio Web Deploy, and don't think I have had the option of naming my deployment.  I can choose which slot I deploy to however, which is either Production or Staging. But again, the URL will be a different GUID if I create a new staging deployment. I looked online for naming deployment slots for Azure Cloud Services but couldn't find anything specific to cloud services.  If you could point me in the right direction of where I could find this documentation that would be great! @benk

Comment: Tagged the wrong user in my previous comment i think @benv

Comment: Hmm, I guess that feature is specific to Azure websites.  But there are other ways to write the rules without knowing the staging URL.  I've updated my answer with another example.