# How to exclude Azure slots from IIS Redirect Rule

Tags: azure, iis, url-rewriting

I have a website hosted by Azure , I have 2 slots main and staging. I wrote a condition for redirecting non-www to www like following:

```
 <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

My problem is this rule is applying also for the staging slot, like if I typed https://mydomain-staging.azurewebsites.net it redirect me to https://www.mydomain-staging.azurewebsites.net so I couldn't test my staging slot !.

I need to write a rule to exclude my slots which ends with `azurewebsites.net`

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971357/azure-cloud-service-ssl-redirect-from-staging-to-production-slot) answer but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding this condition :

```
  <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^.*\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: There you go, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways. Instead of a catch-all (.*), you can specify the domains you want to redirect. 
The other way is to put a condition where if the host name matches *.azurewebsites.net , ignore

Comment: Could you please provide an example , much appreciated.